# Difference between memory map of static 2-d array and dynamic 2-d array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

from my understanding when we create array using pointers like this

```
    int **ptr = new int*[2];

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
     {
       ptr[i] = new int[3];
     }
```

it would look something like this
[image]

but when we create a static array like this

```
 int arr[2][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

and now if we run the following code

```
cout<<"Address of arr = "<<&arr;
cout<<"arr is pointing to = "<<*arr;
```

it shows the same address, which means arr is pointer which is pointing to itself, which seems very confusing because if array is double pointer then how can it point to itself.

clearly compiler is doing some odd things behind the scene. could you please explain how this works.

Comment: `arr` is not a pointer. `arr` is an array. Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays. Freedom is slavery.

Comment: He is right (although arrays are commonly implicitly converted to arrays and pointers have a `[]` operator)

Comment: Try casting your array to a pointer before taking the address and then you should get what you expect (ie.  `int* arr_ptr = arr;`).  Then `cout << "Address of arr:" << arr_ptr << endl; cout << "Array pointing to:" << *arr_ptr << endl;`

Comment: @DarthRubik - there is no **cast** in your code. There is an **implicit conversion**.

Comment: @PeteBecker It is an implicit cast (at least that is how I think about it)

Comment: @DarthRubik - there's no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: @DarthRubik: PeteBecker is correct. There is a significant difference between implicit conversion and cast: the latter inhibits warnings, the first is well defined, the latter tells the compiler to "shut up and eat it".

Comment: Your code is C++, not C. Both are different languages. Operator overloading and different semantics can change the behaviour.

Comment: @DarthRubik Not only do pointers have a `[]` operator, strictly speaking (in C, at least), arrays do *not* have a `[]` operator!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it shows the same address, which means arr is pointer which is
>   pointing to itself

No, it doesn't mean that. What it means is that the address of `arr` is the same as the address of `arr[0][0]`. This makes perfect sense, because `arr[0][0]` is part of `arr`, and is in fact at the very beginning of it. Similarly, you will find my left arm in the exact same location as you will find me.

The difference between `&arr` and `*arr` is the type. `&arr` is of type `int (*)[2][3]` (pointer to an array of 2 arrays of 3 ints), whereas `*arr` is of type `int[3]` (array of 3 ints). This difference is not expressed by your `cout` statements, simply because `operator<<` is not defined to express it.

Comment: so it means they have same address but different physical existence in memory. @KerrekSB

Comment: No, @Balraj . A pointer is a variable that points to something else, so you have the address of the pointer and the address of the something else at which the pointer points. An array *is* the array. It doesn't point at anything. It is the storage. There is only one address involved: The array's.